# When you think of time what is the closest thing that it relates to?

Tags: time

i am writing an essay and summary about what is related to time and i get that a dimension and space are what time is like. can you help me out on this one.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a physics question in its current form.

Comment: You could start by watching the recent videos from Minutephysics on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKbJ9leUNDE

Answer (score 1):

I think of entropy, the thermodynamic/statistical mechanic quantity that can only increase in the universe over time.  Entropy could be considered a measure of disorder in a system, though this is not entirely rigorous, since how chaotic or disorderly something is could be subjective.  Specifically, entropy is defined as follows: $$ S = k \log W $$  Here S is entropy, k is Boltzmann's constant, and W is the multiplicity, or number of microstates corresponding to a given macrostate.